# Apache mod_rewrite path to query string for specific path format

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string, friendly-url

I've been working on this for weeks.  I want to be able to use a friendly URL to pass variables to a PHP script.  For example, if someone uses this URL:

https://example.com/foo/bar/who

I would like my PHP script to receive this:

https://example.com/index.php/?var1=foo&var2=bar&var3=who

The catch is that I ONLY want to do this rewrite when there are three vars in the path.  If there are fewer or more than three, I do not want to rewrite the URL.

I've seen several other explanations related to this type of rewrite but nothing quite like this.

This is almost working, but not quite.  I only want the rewrite done if there's something present for those first three variables.  I know this is incomplete, but with this method at least the REQUEST_URI contains the values I can parse.  But again, I only want to do this when there are three vars in the path.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^index\.php/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php [L]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please do add your tried htaccess rule file in your question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close, have it this way. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. You had already created back references only thing you needed to use them, which I have added those now.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you .. that actually fixes the first part.  What can be done to make this rule work ONLY when there are three parms in the URL.  What happens is that this also rewrites URLs referring to my CSS, JS and other files.  If I could have it rewrite ONLY when the URL is in the form of /a/b/c (three items), I think that would fix it.  Or, run the rule ONLY if the request doesn't include a .js .php or .css file.

Comment: @MichaelJ, You may need to use base tag to fix your js and other relative resources. If you are linking js files using a relative path then the file will obviously get a 404 because its looking for URL path. for example if the URL path is /file/ instead of file.html then your relative resources are loading from /file/ which is not a directory but rewritten html file. To fix this make your links absolute or use base tag. In the header of your webpage add this `<base href="/">` so that your relative links can load from the correct location.

Comment: That was it!  I didn't realize I was using relative paths for a few of my JS/CSS files.  Thank you for the huge assist.

Comment: @MichaelJ, your welcome, cheers and happy learning.